# convert image to mnist format

Tags: python, image-processing, mnist

I want to convert images to mnist format,with black digits and white background. the output should look like this [image]

but I am getting output like this  [image]

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def imageprepare(argv):

im = Image.open(argv).convert('L')
width = float(im.size[0])
height = float(im.size[1])
newImage = Image.new('L', (28, 28), (255))  # creates white canvas of 28x28 pixels

if width > height:  # check which dimension is bigger
    # Width is bigger. Width becomes 20 pixels.
    nheight = int(round((20.0 / width * height), 0))  # resize height according to ratio width
    if (nheight == 0):  # rare case but minimum is 1 pixel
        nheight = 1
        # resize and sharpen
    img = im.resize((20, nheight), Image.ANTIALIAS).filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
    wtop = int(round(((28 - nheight) / 2), 0))  # calculate horizontal position
    newImage.paste(img, (4, wtop))  # paste resized image on white canvas
else:
    # Height is bigger. Heigth becomes 20 pixels.
    nwidth = int(round((20.0 / height * width), 0))  # resize width according to ratio height
    if (nwidth == 0):  # rare case but minimum is 1 pixel
        nwidth = 1
        # resize and sharpen
    img = im.resize((nwidth, 20), Image.ANTIALIAS).filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
    wleft = int(round(((28 - nwidth) / 2), 0))  # caculate vertical pozition
    newImage.paste(img, (wleft, 4))  # paste resized image on white canvas

newImage.save("D:/Desktop/desktop/MNIST/sample1.png")

tv = list(newImage.getdata())  # get pixel values

# normalize pixels to 0 and 1. 0 is pure white, 1 is pure black.
tva = [(255 - x) * 1.0 / 255.0 for x in tv]
print(tva)
return tva

x=imageprepare('D:/Desktop/desktop/MNIST/0/2.bmp')#file path here
print(len(x))# mnist IMAGES are 28x28=784 pixels
```

Can you please help me where should I modify the code? Thank you :)

[Desired output]: [image]

[Output I am getting]: [image]

Comment: please share the input image

Comment: here's the Input image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHVax.png

Comment: Hope [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Lguo.png) is what you are looking for. If so perform Otsu threshold and resize to dimensions of your choice.